# БСП или СПП? Двоеточие или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, бсп, двоеточие

В предложении *"Сейчас мы узнаем: гуманитарий ты или технарь"* допустимо ставить запятую вместо двоеточия? Насколько это правильно? И на основании какого правила ставится двоеточие?

Answer (score 3):

***Сейчас мы узнаем, гуманитарий ты или технарь.***

В этом предложении можно поставить **запятую.**

Придаточное предложение должно было присоединяться к главному союзом-частицей ЛИ, в данном предложении опущенной из-за наличия между существительными союза ИЛИ - для благозвучия, так сказать. На мой взгляд, это сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным.

***Ср.: Сейчас мы узнаем, гуманитарий ЛИ ты.
Сейчас мы узнаем, гуманитарий ЛИ ты ИЛИ технарь.***

Answer (score 1):

1) Передача вопросительной речи в **БСП**: **Мы его спрашиваем: гуманитарий ты или технарь?** Сравнить: Мы его спросили: "Гуманитарий ты или технарь?"

Здесь БСП является упрощенным вариантом  **предложения  с прямой речью,**  например: Мы с удивлением спрашивали: неужели Сильвио не будет драться?

2) Передача вопросительной речи в **СПП** (изъяснительная часть присоединяется вопросительным союзным словом или частицей ЛИ):  Сейчас мы узнаем, кто ты. Сейчас мы узнаем, гуманитарий ли ты?  **Сейчас мы узнаем, гуманитарий (ли) ты  или технарь.**

**Примечание.** Частица ЛИ, действительно, пропускается при наличии союз ИЛИ, который  является как бы  "определителем" вопросительной части. Также  встречаются  предложения такого типа (тоже без частицы ЛИ): **Пойду узнаю, может быть, есть что-то новое**. В этом случае вводное слово выступает в роли союза.

Comment: Т.е. получается, что запятая даже уместнее, чем двоеточие?

Comment: Да, уместнее.  Потому что глагол" узнать" используется в СПП (ставится запятая),  а в БСП  (ставится двоеточие) больше подходит  глагол "спросить", как и в предложении с прямой речью.

Comment: Вот теперь я совсем запуталась... Вы пишите, что уместнее запятая, но при этом же пишете, что в БСП ставится двоеточие. (предложение в моем вопросе БСП)

Comment: Ваше предложение - это СПП с запятой, а не БСП  с двоеточием.  Выбор зависит от семантики глагола: узнать  – это СПП, а спросить/спрашивать – это БСП или прямая речь.

Comment: Вот это новость.

Comment: Т.е. правильно:
Сейчас мы узнаем, гуманитарий ты или технарь.
НО:
Сейчас мы спросим: гуманитарий ты или технарь.
??

Comment: Да, только второе предложение неестественно звучит. Лучше так: Мы хотим спросить: гуманитарий ты или технарь?